Why do PIL and plt.imshow display different images when using the same tensor in Python?
I am trying to convert a PyTorch tensor to a PIL image and display it using both matplotlib.pyplot and PIL. However, I am noticing that the images displayed by plt.imshow and PIL's display() function look different from each other.
imshow

PIL

Below is the function I am using to perform the conversion and display the images:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

def tensor_to_pil(image_tensor):
    print(image_tensor[0].shape)
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(image_tensor[0].cpu().squeeze().numpy(), cmap='gray')

    if image_tensor.shape[1] == 1:
        pil_image = Image.fromarray(image_tensor[0].cpu().squeeze().numpy(), "L")
    else:
        # This seems to be an error in the code where 'error' is not defined
        # error
        pil_image = Image.fromarray(image_tensor[0].permute(1, 2, 0).cpu().numpy())
    print("yes")
    display(pil_image)
    print("yes")



Tensor Dimensions: The tensor I am using is a grayscale image (1 color channel) , image_tensor variable have dimension torch.Size([1,1,640,640])
What could be causing the difference in how plt.imshow and PIL display the same image tensor? Is there any additional processing I need to do to align their outputs?

It seems the PIL.Image.fromarray function only takes in a set of datatypes for conversion (as can be seen in https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray).
For your case, I tried out converting the torch array to np.uint32 and it worked.
You can do this with :
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display
def tensor_to_pil(image_tensor):
    print(image_tensor[0].shape)
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(image_tensor[0].cpu().squeeze().numpy(), cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
    # print((image_tensor[0].cpu().squeeze().numpy()))
    if image_tensor.shape[1] == 1:
        pil_image = Image.fromarray(image_tensor[0].cpu().squeeze().numpy().astype(np.uint32))
    else:
        # This seems to be an error in the code where 'error' is not defined
        # error
        pil_image = Image.fromarray(image_tensor[0].permute(1, 2, 0).cpu().numpy())
    print("yes")
    display(pil_image)
    print("yes")

